# Abstract border and text block into another style/template in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

First of all, I would like to add customized text blocks to my GUI with the least possible overhead. For instance: `<TextBlock style={StaticRessources myTextBlock}>Text</TextBlock>`

For now I have the following border style:

```
<Style x:Key="greenBox" TargetType="Border">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00FF00"/>
  <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
</Style>
```

And I apply it in the following way:

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource greenBox}">
  <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Custom Text</TextBlock>
</Border>
```

My problem is, it needs 2 Tags and the properties set in the TextBlock will be redunant. I cannot figure out how to abstract both definitions into a single element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's where Label comes into play:

```
<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="greenLabel">    
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">        
        <Setter.Value>            
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                <Border Style="{StaticResource greenBox}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>                
            </ControlTemplate>            
        </Setter.Value>        
    </Setter>    
</Style>

<Label Style="{StaticResource greenLabel}">Custom Text</Label>
```

(in accordance with your other question: if this is the only place you use that borderstyle you can of course include these directly in that border not using an extra style)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom control as described [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html). Or you could create a [UserControl](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/UserControl.aspx) as well.